# What to do when lucadegasperi oauth2 server for laravel gets caught by auth middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

So currently building an oauth2 server with:

- https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/authorization-server/auth-code.md

  - Auth Grant
- laravel 5.2

Now no where in the instructions does it address what to do when the user is not logged in. (which most times will be the case)

So in that scenario - the user hits the auth middleware kicking them to the login screen... but what to do after that? There is nothing passed to the login page? so how do i know where to redirect the user back to?

Now yes of course I can just do this on my own, but before I do that I just want to make sure I am not missing anything? again it was not address in the documentation, so I can only assume this was thought through?

Let me know your thoughts.

Steve

Comment: I don't think the functionality you're describing is mutually exclusive to oAuth functionality. That said, you'll have to implement this yourself. There's always the `back()` method in Laravel.

Comment: return->back() would send me back to my /oauth page sure. but the query string is lost at that point so client values etc are nulled out...

Comment: You should be able to `return back()->withInput();`

Comment: and actually return back() does not work assuming because the /oauth page never technically loads? I just 302s over to the login page? : 
 /oauth/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_uri=http://domain.dev/test&response_type=code 302 text/html Other 687 B 73 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just ended up doing a work around in my Authenticate.php file. Incase anyone else is curious I did this:

```
            $params = [];
            if($request->has('client_id'))
                $params['client_id'] = $request->client_id;
            if($request->has('redirect_uri'))
                $params['redirect_uri'] = $request->redirect_uri;
            if($request->has('response_type'))
                $params['response_type'] = $request->response_type;
            if($request->has('scope'))
                $params['scope'] = $request->scope;
            if($request->has('state'))
                $params['state'] = $request->state;

            return redirect()->route('login', $params);
            //return redirect()->guest('login');
```

Passed this to my loginController. Then in loginController:

```
        $params = [];
        if($this->request->has('redirect_uri'))
            $params['redirect_uri'] = $this->request->redirect_uri;
        if($this->request->has('response_type'))
            $params['response_type'] = $this->request->response_type;
        if($this->request->has('scope'))
            $params['scope'] = $this->request->scope;
        if($this->request->has('state'))
            $params['state'] = $this->request->state;
        if($this->request->has('client_id'))
        {
            $params['client_id'] = $this->request->client_id;
            //dd($params);
            return redirect()->route('oauth.authorize.get', $params);
        }
```

Let me know if you see any issues.

Cheers

Citti